# Slow LINQ operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am having the following code:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetCloseZipCodes(int zipcode, int radius)
        {
            PycDBDataContext db = new PycDBDataContext();

            ZipCode reqZipInfo = ZipCodes.Instance.zipcodes[zipcode];

            if (reqZipInfo == null)
                return new int[] { };

            double longt = LongitudePlusDistance((double)reqZipInfo.Longitude, (double)reqZipInfo.Latitude, radius);
            double latit = LatitudePlusDistance((double)reqZipInfo.Latitude, radius);
            double minLong = 2 * (double)reqZipInfo.Longitude - longt;
            double minLat = 2 * (double)reqZipInfo.Latitude - latit;

            var zips = ZipCodes.Instance.zipcodes.Where(x => (double)x.Value.Longitude >= minLong &&
                                                  (double)x.Value.Longitude <= longt &&
                                                  (double)x.Value.Latitude >= minLat &&
                                                  (double)x.Value.Latitude <= latit &&
                                                  CalcDistance((double)reqZipInfo.Longitude,
                                                  (double)reqZipInfo.Latitude, 
                                                  (double)x.Value.Longitude, 
                                                  (double)x.Value.Latitude) <= radius).Select(x => x.Key);

            return zips;
        }
```

This function is given with a zipcode, a radius and it will find all the zipcodes within the radius.
I have performance issues here and after running dotTrace most of my time is in the following:

```
var zips = ZipCodes.Instance.zipcodes.Where(x => (double)x.Value.Longitude >= minLong &&
                                                  (double)x.Value.Longitude <= longt &&
                                                  (double)x.Value.Latitude >= minLat &&
                                                  (double)x.Value.Latitude <= latit &&
                                                  CalcDistance((double)reqZipInfo.Longitude,
                                                  (double)reqZipInfo.Latitude, 
                                                  (double)x.Value.Longitude, 
                                                  (double)x.Value.Latitude) <= radius).Select(x => x.Key);
```

And third of the time there, it is accessing

```
public System.Nullable<decimal> Longitude
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Longitude;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Longitude != value))
                {
                    this._Longitude = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I improve the performance??? We are talking about a few seconds here...
I can't understand why. this is all cached and non-SQL.

Comment: How many records is it matching against?

Comment: My first thought would be that the CalcDistance method is the bottleneck as it's called for every item.  Try creating an actual method to replace your lambda expression with and then it will be easier to put some timers around it and further isolate the problem.  I don't see anything but that method that could be doing it though.  Perhaps you could post the contents of CalcDistance?

Comment: If you use the return value of `GetCloseZipCodes` many times, you can try to convert the it `ToList` or `ToArray`, to eliminate multiple calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, you're doing a *lot* of conversions between `double` and `decimal` as far as I can see.

I'd suggest *either* changing your object representation to use `double` to start with, *or* convert `longt` and `latit` to `decimal` so that you can perform all the comparisons in a single type, without all the conversions.

Aside from anything else, keeping one consistent representation will leave your code *cleaner* as well as probably performing better. In this case, I'd say that `double` is probably a more appropriate representation than `decimal` anyway - it's not like these are *exact* decimal values like currency; they're naturally-occurring values which have already been approximated by measurement.

Additionally, you're doing the nullable to non-nullable conversion several times, both for `x.Value` *and* for comparisons. Consider using a statement lambda instead:

```
x => {
   if (x.Longitude == null || x.Latitude == null)
   {
       return false;
   }
   double longitude = x.Value.Longitude.Value;
   double latitude = x.Value.Latitude.Value;
   return longitude >= minLong &&
          longitude <= longt &&
          latitude >= minLat &&
          latitude <= latit &&
          longitude >= minLong &&
          CalcDistance(reqZipInfo.Longitude, reqZipInfo.Latitude,
                       longitude, latitude) <= radius;
}
```

For the sake of readability, I'd probably put this in a separate method to be honest.

(Do you even need the properties to be nullable, by the way? It doesn't make much sense to me.)